# Get rid of an embedded YouTube player after video has finished

Tags: youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I currently have the below code to play a youtube video on a page.

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
//Load player api asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'egm': 0, 'showsearch': 0, },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    //When the video has ended
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        //Get rid of the player
    }
}
```

The onPlayerStateChange function finds out when the player has finished playing the video.
How can I then make this player disappear?

Comment: Simply remove the element with id "player".

Answer (score 5):

If you are using IFRAME API :

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    //When the video has ended
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        //Get rid of the player
        event.target.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is documentation to the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event,element) {
    //When the video has ended
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        //Get rid of the player
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```